# when I try to login on sandbox.paypal page, it redirects to sandbox3.paypal

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

I create a donation page on my website using NVP (Paypal) method. When user submits the form it redirects to sandbox.paypal, where he/she can see the detail of donation and options to donate using credit card or paypal account.

When he tries to login to his paypal account it redirects him to sandbox3.paypal login page and when he logs in to sandbox3.paypal it shows him dashboard.

He is not able to give donation because he is redirected to his dashboard.

Comment: I have same problem with the caveat that first you get an error because you are redirected to www.sandbox3.paypal as opposed to https://www.sandbox3.paypal which is insecure. Then if you override that you get to the dashboard (of my test user account in my case but same thing really as above)